# I can I get a background Color of button? [Android Studio]

Tags: android, button, colors, background

I made a method like this:

```
public void points(Button btn)
{

    Drawable buttonBackground = btn.getBackground(); //doesn't work
    if(buttonBackground.equals(Color.RED))
        counter++;
    else if(buttonBackground.equals(Color.BLACK))
        counter-=10;
    else if(buttonBackground.equals(Color.rgb(212,175,55)))
        counter+=10;
}
```

I want to know the background color of the button and the android doesn't have(I think) `button.getBackground.getColor()` or something like that. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: *Is it possible?* only if Drawable is instance of `ColorDrawable`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PaintDrawable drawable = (PaintDrawable) btn.getBackground();
int color = drawable.getPaint().getColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferred way of doing this kind of conditional check is

1. Create style.cml and define colour and fonts there
2. Use these styles in your layout when declaring buttons or textviews
3. Once done then you can use get style and  run your switch case on style

If helps when you are planning to create an enterprise app